# Solcalendar, syncing with Owncloud

Tags: android, synchronization, caldav, owncloud

I'm trying to configure Solcalendar to sync with owncloud 6.0.0.
I used "Custom" option and type there

http://hostname/owncloud/remote.php/caldav/calendars/[myUsername]/[myCalendarNAme]

And of course my login anc password.

I get the message "Check ID and password and try again". Any ideas what can be wrong here?

Syncing with Lightning (Thunderbird) works well using that link.

Comment: do you use any special characters in your password (i.e. non-alphanumeric characters)? if so, try to use a password without

Comment: same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Just wrote a complete tutorial about connecting ownCloud with Windows and Android. There you find anything you need to know: http://www.kwoxer.de/2016/05/05/owncloud-mit-thunderbird-und-android-verbinden-komplettanleitung/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same prob. Solved it (on Android) by installing an additional CalDavsync App called https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.gege.caldavsyncadapter&hl=de
Probably that is helpful for you.